# Extract data from a table with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I master HtmlAgilityPack. I'm trying to get data from a pre-loaded page. Namely:
There is a page 1.htm.
I want to get the value from the table opposite the line "Operating system". (the document itself is attached).
I do this:

```
private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Создаю экземпляр класса
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            // Загружаю файл
            doc.Load(@"D:\(тут путь к файлу)\1.htm");
            // Пытаюсь получить информацию из ноды, но получаю null
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode bodyNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//TD[@CLASS=pt]");
            ...
```

In general, it is necessary to extract a lot of information from the file, but I think that if one line is obtained, then further by analogy.

The required line was as follows:

```
 private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Создаю экземпляр класса
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            // Загружаю файл
            doc.Load(@"D:\(тут путь к файлу)\1.htm");

            foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body/table[2]/tr[8]/td[4]"))
            {
                string stroka = node.InnerText;
            }
```

But this option is "on the forehead." If you do not change the structure of my document. And how it is possible with the help of the search has not figured out yet.

[File](http://fayloobmennik.cloud/7263750)

Comment: in the second code block you posted are you trying to extract cells from current line? I ask you because this is extracting from body

Comment: In the second fragment, I got the result I needed, but if I change the document structure (adding one more table or row to the table), I will get the wrong data.

Comment: `foreach`? [tag:c]? Also, I only have rough guesses what your comments could mean ... something about an "example class"? Could you translate these please?

Comment: Oh wait ... this must be C#! Someone revise that pending edit please to correct the tag, I already approved it so I'm out of options for the moment ....

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking. Do you want elements on second column from that table?

Comment: "с#" of course. I made a mistake

Comment: Yes, by entering the value of the element from the first column, I want to get the value from the second.

Comment: I've updated tags for you. Good luck.

Comment: `doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//TD[@CLASS=pt]");` should be `doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//td[@class='pt']");`. Xpath is case-sensitive and single quotation marks around pt were missing.

Comment: How to get the value after the <TR> <TD> <TD> <TD> tags Операционная система & nbsp; & nbsp; <TD>

Comment: the table contains duplicates,for example you have USB-устройство multiple times, so you can't enter a text and get a value from the other column

Comment: I do not need to get all the values from the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return a dictionary of tables by name. Each table is a dictionary with first column as key and second for value.

```
var tables = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"D:\(тут путь к файлу)\1.htm", Encoding.GetEncoding(1251), false);
var tableNames = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='pt']/a").Select(a=>a.Attributes["name"].Value);
foreach(string name in tableNames)
{
    var table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[.//a[@name='" + name + "']]/following-sibling::table[1]");
    int columns = table.SelectNodes(".//tr[1]/td").Count();

    string[] keys = table.SelectNodes(".//tr/td["+(columns-1)+"]").Select(n => n.InnerText.Replace("&nbsp;"," ").Trim()).ToArray();
    string[] values = table.SelectNodes(".//tr/td["+columns+"]").Select(n => n.InnerText.Replace("&nbsp;"," ").Trim()).ToArray();
    var body = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.Count(); i++)
    {
        string key = keys[i];
        if (body.ContainsKey(key))
            body[key] += ", " + values[i];
        else if( key!="" && values[i]!="")
            body[key] = values[i];

    }
    tables.Add(name, body);

}
```

For example `tables["power management"]` returns 4 entries:

> - [0] {[Текущий источник питания, Электросеть]}   System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
> - [1] {[Состояние батарей, Нет батареи]}  System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
> - [2] {[Полное время работы от батарей, Неизвестно]}  System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
> - [3] {[Оставшееся время работы от батарей, Неизвестно]}  System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair

and `tables["power management"]["Текущий источник питания"]` returns:

> "Электросеть"

For iterating you can do:

```
foreach(var tableName in tables.Keys)
{
    var table = tables[tableName];
    foreach(var key in table.Keys)
    {
        string value = table[key];
        Debug.Print(tableName + "/" + key + "/" + value);
    }
}
```